# strace-like program for Windows/MSVC

Tags: c++, dll, dependencies

ALL,

I'm developing a program with MSVC 2010 in C++ which contains of one executable binary and couple of dlls. Some dlls are exporting classes and some - exporting functions. There are also some dependencies between those dlls.

At one point when I built the program one of the dlls stops working and I get the error "error 126: the specified module could not be found".

When I had this situation on Linux I got a suggestion to use strace to see what dependency is missing from the so. However this is Windows and MSVC and I'm not sure there is a tool like this.

Or maybe there is a program inside the MSVC package which can look inside the dll and tell me if there is a missing dependency?

Thank you.

Comment: http://www.dependencywalker.com/

Comment: Beside being a possible duplicate, it is also pretty broad, IMO. And dependency walker is indeed an excellent suggestion. Not inside the MSVC package, but well known and often used, and a free download.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, thank you. I guess I need to learn how to google properly. ;-)